# Generate an AxesImage from an array without displaying the image

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig, ax= pyplot.subplots(1,1)
ax_img=ax.imshow(array) # returns AxesImage object and displays image.
```

The above code can return an AxesImage object but also displays the image.

I want to skip the display altogether and simply generate the AxesImage object using the array without displaying anything.

Comment: The code should not display anything. If it does, you are in some environment that is configured to automatically do stuff. Which environment is that?

Comment: I'm using Spyder

Comment: Check the spyder settings, where you can deactivate matplotlib support